# Inicio JCalendar + ComboBox = Jcalendar Final

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-8.2, jcalendar, jdatechooser

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hola a todos, de ante mano agradezco el apoyo estoy intentando realizar una suma desde un

```
jDateChoose(Ingreso Planilla) + Tiempo de Contrato(ComboBox(3 meses, 6 meses)) = Termino de Contrato(jDateChooser)
```

agradezco me den algunas ideas de como instancia esta suma.

Comment: ¿A cierta fecha quieres agregar n meses? ¿Qué resultado esperas si por ejemplo la fecha seleccionada es 28 de febrero ó 31 de diciembre?

Comment: Fecha Ingreso de planilla al selecionar ejemplo 01/01/2020 cuanndo seleccione el combo box ejemplo 3 meses que sume y se muestro en termino de contrato, claro que la fecha ingreso y termino de contrato son JDateChooser

Comment: Has dado ejemplos de datos de entrada, pero seguimos sin ejemplos de resultado esperado.

Answer (score 0):

Adiciono una suma de días con jcalendar espero te ayude a la conversion de meses

Modifico el código entendi que es suma de meses en este caso es por dias
tengo ambas formas

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.Date;


public class Diasincapacidad extends javax.swing.JInternalFrame {

  
    public Diasincapacidad() {
        initComponents();
    }
public void incapacidad(){
    Date fecha = jDfechainicio.getDate(); 
    
    long dias = (Long.parseLong(jTdiasinc.getText())*(1000*60*60*24)); //trasladar los dias a long   
    DateFormat df= DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM);
       String finiString=df.format(fecha);
       try{fecha=df.parse(finiString);}
       catch(ParseException ex){}
       long finiMs = fecha.getTime();
       long difingreso=finiMs+(dias-1);
       
       String fnueString = df.format(difingreso);
       
       double diasingreso = Math.floor(difingreso/(1000*60*60*24));//trasladar el long a dias
       jFTfecha.setText(fnueString);
}
    
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">//GEN-BEGIN:initComponents
    private void initComponents() {

        jCalendar1 = new com.toedter.calendar.JCalendar();
        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jDfechainicio = new com.toedter.calendar.JDateChooser();
        jTdiasinc = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        btncalculo = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jFTfecha = new javax.swing.JFormattedTextField();

        jPanel1.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Calculo de Fechas de incapacidades"));

        jDfechainicio.setDateFormatString("dd/MM/yyyy");

        jLabel1.setText("Dias");

        jLabel2.setText("Inicio de la incapacidad");

        jLabel3.setText("Fin de la incapacidad");

        btncalculo.setText("Generar");
        btncalculo.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btncalculoActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jFTfecha.setEditable(false);
        jFTfecha.setFormatterFactory(new javax.swing.text.DefaultFormatterFactory(new javax.swing.text.DateFormatter(new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy"))));

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                            .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(jDfechainicio, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(jLabel1)
                            .addComponent(jTdiasinc, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 54, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(jLabel3)
                            .addComponent(jFTfecha))
                        .addGap(6, 6, 6)
                        .addComponent(btncalculo)))
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jDfechainicio, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jTdiasinc, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jLabel3)
                        .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 42, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(btncalculo)
                            .addComponent(jFTfecha, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addContainerGap())))
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(jCalendar1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(21, 21, 21)
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(72, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(14, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(jCalendar1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>//GEN-END:initComponents

    private void btncalculoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_btncalculoActionPerformed
      incapacidad();
    }//GEN-LAST:event_btncalculoActionPerformed


    // Variables declaration - do not modify//GEN-BEGIN:variables
    private javax.swing.JButton btncalculo;
    private com.toedter.calendar.JCalendar jCalendar1;
    private com.toedter.calendar.JDateChooser jDfechainicio;
    private javax.swing.JFormattedTextField jFTfecha;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTdiasinc;
    // End of variables declaration//GEN-END:variables
}
```

Este script suma dias de dos fechas con jcalendar en java 8

Comment: Modifique el código por que es adición de días.